# How can lines in Plotly chart be properly color-coded based on Category or Subcategory?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

I have a dataframe like this

```
    Category    Subcategory Date    Value
0   Category A  Subcategory A1  01/01/2016  31250
1   Category A  Subcategory A1  01/02/2016  32250
2   Category A  Subcategory A1  01/01/2017  32500
3   Category A  Subcategory A1  01/02/2017  33000
4   Category A  Subcategory A1  01/01/2018  32500
```

I'd like to create a Plotly line chart that represents the values for each Subcategory but I'd like the lines to be colored based on the Category. A pretty straightforward task, but I experience a behavior I cannot explain...

This is the code and the result:

```
fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="Date",
    y="Value",
    color="Category",
    # color="Subcategory",
)
fig.show()
```

[Dataframe plotted with color="Category"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em0LL.png)

The same code with color set to Subcategory works fine:

```
fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="Date",
    y="Value",
    # color="Category",
    color="Subcategory",
)
fig.show()
```

[Dataframe plotted with color="Subcategory"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcLCT.png)

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Does adding line_group="Subcategory" make any difference?

Comment: Indeed it does. Adding line_group="Subcategory" to color="Category" solves the issue. Many thanks.